# Alterações com IOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, deprecated

Eu estava programando utilizando a linguagem **Objective-C** e quando foi realizado o update do `Xcode 7` surgiram alguns erros na linguagem, um deles está no arquivo `AppDelegate.m`:

```
(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        return nil;
    }

    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

Para a linha em destaque ele exibe o seguinte erro:

> init is deprecated - Use initWithConcurrencyType:instead

Como que devo escrever esta nova estrutura no lugar do `init`?

Answer (score 0):

Apenas troque dessa forma:

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:]
```